# How to keep button width in proportion to screen size using weights?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout

I am creating an xml file. There I have two buttons on bottom of the screen. Both needs same width. So I done that by layout_weight(Check Fig 1. )

[image: Fig 1. large Screen]

```
         Fig 1.
```

Now when I reduced the screen size in emulator I got screen like this(Check Fig 2.),
[image: Fig 2.]

```
         Fig 2.
```

But I need view like in First screen for all phone size. Any one can help me plz ? Thanks in advance.
Kindly check the attached code.

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llDetailsBottomButton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Yes I am Ready "
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img1"
        android:background="@color/orange" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Not Now"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img2"
        android:background="@color/oange" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry,, I forgot to use 
        android:layout_height="match_parent".

Comment: did your problem solved?

Comment: is yopur prblm solved or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry,, I forgot to use

```
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

It solved my issue,,,